# How do i solve this TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, opencv, path, google-colaboratory

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while 1:
    ret,img = cap.read()
    image = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/signProject/amer_sign2.png')
    cv2_imshow(image)
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    top, right, bottom, left = 75, 350, 300, 590
    roi = img[top:bottom, right:left]
    roi=cv2.flip(roi,1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
    cv2_imshow(gray)
    alpha=classify(gray)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0,255,0), 2)
    font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(img,alpha,(0,130),font,5,(0,0,255),2)
    #cv2.resize(img,(1000,1000))
    cv2_imshow(img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key==ord('q'):
        break;
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-36-105ee52e9f68> in <module>()
      6     img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
      7     top, right, bottom, left = 75, 350, 300, 590
----> 8     roi = img[top:bottom, right:left]
      9     roi=cv2.flip(roi,1)
     10     gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLsjb.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5lZd.png)

Answer (score 2):

The error means you are trying to index an object which can't be indexed (in this case a `NoneType`). So `img` in line 8 seems to be `None`.
This is probably due to `ret, img = cap.read()` failing. The first return value in `cap.read()` (in your case called `ret`) indicates whether or not `cap.read()` was sucessful. You should check if `ret` is `True` before using `img`.

### Why is `cap.read()` failing?

There could be a couple of reasons why it fails. Here's what I would do to find the cause of the problem:

##### Try other indices

I read a couple of times that cameras in OpenCV are not always at index `0`, but may as well be at `-1` or some other positive index.

##### Check if FFMPEG codec is installed

You need the FFMPEG codec to read video with OpenCV. You can print OpenCV Build Information with `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`. It should show a section labelled `Video I/O`. In that section there should be an entry labelled `FFMPEG`, which is either `YES` or `NO`. If it's `NO`, you need to install OpenCV with FFMPEG

##### Verify that your camera works

In case you're using an external camera, make sure it's properly connected and working (e.g by using it with another program).

Comment: yes it is false . how do i correct it?

Comment: I edited my answer and added some things you might try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that, for some reason, `img` is equal to `None`, so `roi = img[top:bottom, right:left]` triggers the error.